# Objective-C Async call for Google Long Running Speech API is not returning Operation status true?

Tags: asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, google-speech-api

I am having issue when using Google asynchronous speech recognition long running API. The `operation.done` is not returning true.

I had modified the objective-C sample program https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Objective-C/Speech-gRPC-Nonstreaming/Speech/SpeechRecognitionService.m to use longruning API.

Here are the modified snippet -

```
// prepare a single gRPC call to make the request
GRPCProtoCall *call = [client RPCToLongRunningRecognizeWithRequest:recognizeRequest
                                                            handler:
                        ^(Operation *operation, NSError *nserror) {
                            if (nserror) {
                                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", nserror);
                                completion([nserror description]);
                            } else {
                                NSLog(@"RESPONSE name %@", operation.name);
                                while (!operation.done) {
                                    NSLog(@"operation done -  %d", operation.done);
                                    usleep(2000000);
                                }
                                    GPBAny *gpbAny = operation.response;
                                    NSLog(@"RESPONSE typeURL %@", gpbAny.typeURL);
                                    NSLog(@"RESPONSE deescription %@", gpbAny.value.description);
                                    GPBMessage *longRunningResponse = [gpbAny unpackMessageClass:LongRunningRecognizeResponse.class error:nil];
                                    NSLog(@"RESPONSE RECEIVED %@", longRunningResponse);
                                completion(longRunningResponse);
                            }
                        }];
```

It never come out from the `while (!operation.done)` loop. `operation.name` return the correct operation id. I was able to verify using `gcloud ml speech operations describe 2104003022050949209` command that call went to google speech API and it return the transcribed message. But objective-C code does not return the operation.done true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is how gRPC or this API is supposed to work. For gRPC, after you receive the response (the Operation object), its value will no longer change, so while-looping on that will for sure cause infinite loop. LongRunningRecognize method is an asynchronous RPC method, so operation.done == false in this case simply mean that this operation is still running on the server side. You will need the methods in [Operation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Objective-C/Speech-gRPC-Nonstreaming/google/longrunning/operations.proto#L39) service to further interact with the server for result of this request.